# how to properly seal protective sleeve entering electric panel

Tags: electrical-panel

There is a good picture of what my panel will look like at https://www.ecmweb.com/qampa/stumped-code-2

I don't want to copy their picture over here so I'll describe the situation: I'm adding electric service to my pole barn.  The inspector has said that since I have unfinished walls I should sleeve cables below 8' for protection.  The electric code allows for this but one of the rules is that the sleeve for the panel is to be sealed.  I don't see any specific products for sealing conduit with NM cables in it so I wonder if I'm supposed to run all cables and then squirt a bunch of expanding foam into the top of the pipe?  That seems messy so I assume that there is something better.

Is there a proper way to seal this protective sleeve with the NM in it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You're looking for "duct seal" in the electrical section

The correct product for sealing the ends of conduits is something that's called "duct seal" of all things -- it's a soft putty that can be molded around the cables and stuffed into the conduit.  It's available just about anywhere electrical supplies are sold.